Patching an objective C method with NOPs in a Mach-O library
So I am targeting an arm64 Mach-O dynamic library (.dylib), and I want to patch a specific objc method using nops. Here’s the view from binary-ninja:
As you can see, the name of the method is EraseGameFile
Here’s the disassembly from BinaryNinja:
0008263c  void -[Anticheat EraseGameFile](struct Anticheat* __ptr64 self, SEL sel)

0008263c  fc                 cld
0008263d  6f                 outsd
0008263e  baa9fa6701         mov     edx, 0x167faa9
00082643  a9f85f02a9         test    eax, 0xa9025ff8
00082648  f65703             not     byte [edi+0x3]
0008264b  a9f44f04a9         test    eax, 0xa9044ff4
00082650  fd                 std
00082651  7b05               jpo     0x82658

00082653  a9fd430191         test    eax, 0x910143fd

00082658  48                 dec     eax
00082659  1800               sbb     byte [eax], al
0008265b  b008               mov     al, 0x8
0008265d  6543               inc     ebx
0008265f  f9                 stc
00082660  b427               mov     ah, 0x27
00082662  009094c23291       add     byte [eax-0x6ecd3d6c], dl
00082668  0001               add     byte [ecx], al
0008266a  1f                 pop     ds {__return_addr}
0008266b  d6                 salc
0008266c  9f                 lahf
0008266d  fe                 ??

My goal is, how can I patch this correctly with NOPs without smashing the stack, which is what usually happens, without resulting in a crash?

Please don't post images on external sites. The link to your image is already dead...
